# Don't include in gsub period at the end of a sentence

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to do a gsub in R to replace all numbers (exs: $1.48, 1,765, 87) with arrows around it. (<>,<<1,765>>,<<87>>)

Here is my current gsub:

text<-c( "Examples of numbers are one and two, 3, 1,284 and fifty nine.", "This ice pop costs $1.48.")

```
subbedNum<-gsub("\\b([$0-9.,]+)\\b", "<<\\1>>", text)
```

however it results with also placing arrows around a period at the end of a sentence, and doesn't have the $ in the arrows:

```
[1]  "My favorite numbers are  <<8>>, <<3,289>> and <<4>><<.>>"
[2]  "This book costs $<<1.48.>>"
```

expected output is:

```
[1,]"My favorite numbers are  <<8>>, <<3,289>> and <<4>>."
[2,]  "This book costs <<$1.48>>."
```

How can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of word boundary (which could potentially have some edge cases), we can capture the digits succeeding any non-digit, followed by either a dot or comma,, and one or more digits.  In the replacement, use the backreference of the captured group and format it with `<<>>`

```
gsub("[^$0-9.,]([$0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?)\\b", "<<\\1>>", text)
#[1] "Examples of numbers are one and two,<<3>>,<<1,284>> and fifty nine."
#[2] "This ice pop costs<<$1.48>>."
```

#### data

```
text<-c( "Examples of numbers are one and two, 3, 1,284 and fifty nine.", "This ice pop costs $1.48.")
```